# Using Selenium 4 to resize columns in C#

Tags: c#, selenium

I use Selenium 3.141 in some website testing, and would like to update to the current version, Selenium 4.4. My resizing of columns in a table is failing, due to changes made in Selenium Actions.

Here's code that works in Selenium 3.141:

```
  public static void ResetWidthOfGridCell(IWebDriver driver, IWebElement elementToResize, int percentChange)
    {
        //Get Width * Height of Element
        Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
        int divWidth = elementToResize.Size.Width;
        int divHeight = elementToResize.Size.Height;
        OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions.IAction resizable = builder
                .MoveToElement(elementToResize, divWidth, divHeight / 2)
                .ClickAndHold()
                .MoveByOffset(divWidth * percentChange / 100, 0)
                .Release()
                .Build();

        resizable.Perform();
    }
```

In Selenium 4.4 I've tried a few things based on the Selenium documentation.  Everything fails.  Here's my current code (not working):

```
 public static void ResetWidthOfGridCell(IWebDriver driver, IWebElement elementToResize, int percentChange)
    {
        int divWidth = elementToResize.Size.Width;
        int divHeight = elementToResize.Size.Height;
        new Actions(driver)
                .MoveToElement(elementToResize, divWidth, divHeight / 2)
                //.Pause(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5d))
                .ClickAndHold()
                .MoveByOffset(divWidth * percentChange / 100, 0)
                //.MoveToElement(elementToResize, divWidth * percentChange / 100, divHeight / 2) // tried but this didn't work...
                //.Pause(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5d))
                .Release()
                .Build()
                .Perform();
    }
```

Would appreciate any help to get this working.

Answer (score 0):

After re-reading the documentation an idea occurred to me: What if the new webdriver (4.4) has an undocumented change in the way it handles the "MoveToElement" action method.  What if the webdriver calculates from the center of the element, instead of the top-left of the element (as it did previously)?
I tested that idea. AND IT WORKED!!

The new line is (see above):

```
                    .MoveToElement(elementToResize, divWidth /2, 0)
```

I wish the documentation would have noted their change.